# Locale appending 'variation' to language and country code

Tags: java, locale

LocaleContext.getLocale() returns the locale object currently as 'en_US_WOL'. I verified the locale object using breakpoint and looks like en- language English, US - country code of US, WOL - variation (a field of Locale object).
How and why is the variation field getting appending and returned for getLocale() method? and how can I stop that? (LocaleContext is of type ThreadLocal)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html

> The variant argument is a vendor or browser-specific code. For example, use WIN for Windows, MAC for Macintosh, and POSIX for POSIX. Where there are two variants, separate them with an underscore, and put the most important one first. For example, a Traditional Spanish collation might construct a locale with parameters for language, country and variant as: "es", "ES", "Traditional_WIN".

If you're after Locale for specific variant, I presume you can use this constructor:

```
Locale(String language, String country, String variant)
```

Or adjust your browser's locale settings (if your application involves browser at all)

Comment: I need the output to be 'en_US' only. I dont want the variant 'WOL' when I do getLocale(). If there is another function which return only language_CountryCode then I will have to modify my API (LocalContext class) to call that function and return only those 2 values on getLocale()

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this too. Unfortunately I haven't found any build-in method to nicely output lang-country code without Variant so I helped myself with such snippet (maybe would be handy to somebody) :

```
public static String getLanguageCode(Locale locale) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(locale.getLanguage());
    if (locale.getCountry() != null && locale.getCountry().length() > 0) {
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(locale.getCountry());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```